# Is it possible to have a file 'pop-up' when you open it through Qt widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an idea for my project where if I click a button, a file in the build folder will open. However, when I say 'open', I'm referring to how files are opened on our desktop when we interact with it. (We click the file and if it's a text file, it'll open it with notepad and etc; if it is a docx file, it'll open Microsoft Word; if it is xls or csv file, it'll open the file with Microsoft Excel). Is it this possible with Qt? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do that using [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl).